# Edit YAML array with php Symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have a little project in Symfony, where I have to do an authentification system. The Administrator can change some parameters, like the length rules of the password.
I use FosUserBundle.

actually, without edit I have a validation.yml which work well:

```
UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        plainPassword:
          - NotBlank:
              message: "Il faut un mdp"
          - Length:
              min: 5
              max: 255
              minMessage: "Trop court (5 minimum)"
              maxMessage: "Trop Long (2555 maximum)"
              groups: [Registration,Profile]
          - Regex:
              pattern: /[0-9]+/
              message: "Doit inclure un chiffre "
              groups: [Registration,Profile]
          - Regex:
              pattern: /[!@#$%^*_-]+/
              message: "Doit inclure un caractère : '!,@,#,$,%,^,*'  "
              groups: [Registration,Profile]
          - Regex:
              pattern: /[A-Z]+/
              message: "Doit inclure une majuscule  "
              groups: [Registration,Profile]
```

I created a class parameter.php in the same folder:

```
<?php
    namespace UserBundle\Ressources\config;
    class Parameter 
    {   
        public function  __construct()
        {   
            $container->setParameter('UserBundle\Entity\User.properties.plainPassword', '-     Length:\nmin:5\nminMessage:"test"\ngroups: [Registration,Profile]');     
        }
    }
```

and I have add this this line on the top of my validation.yml:

```
   imports:
         - { resource: parameter.php }
```

So I have to problem, first I don't find how edit an array YAML (plainPassword)
And is this way it's the good way to edit a YAML file with PHP? (after I would like to use doctrine and get in the database what I have to put on validation.yml)